# Обработка массива PHP. Достать данные

Tags: php, массивы, динамические-массивы, обработка

Добрый день!

нужна помощь в обработке массива. Ничего не получается.

Нужно вытащить данные из массива params и записать в новый массив сохраняя количество этих элементов в [params] количество неизвестно!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 1
            [uid] => 142
            [name] => Аккаунт
            [order_time] => 2016-09-16
            [date_time1] => 2016-09-17
            [date_time2] => 2016-09-21
            [status] => 1
            [params] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cart_id] => 1
                            [good_id] => 1515
                            [ssysname] => lily
                            [art_code] => 1515
                            [price] => 29.32
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 2
            [uid] => 42
            [name] => Новый тест
            [order_time] => 2016-09-16
            [date_time1] => 2016-09-17
            [date_time2] => 2016-09-21
            [status] => 2
            [params] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cart_id] => 2
                            [good_id] => 1715
                            [ssysname] => rose
                            [art_code] => 1115
                            [price] => 569.32
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cart_id] => 2
                            [good_id] => 5615
                            [ssysname] => irise
                            [art_code] => 9865
                            [price] => 8889.32
                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, мы видим в вопросе массив **$M**, тогда

```
$P = array();
foreach($M as $k => $buket){
  $P = array_merge($P, $buket['params'])
}

var_dump($P); // Посмотрим, что получилось.
```